# Convert HTML file written in Jquery with Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm using `phonegap` to convert my html file into an `android app`. Since I started using Jquery to show/hide images my buttons for this has become numb.

I have both linked to normal jquery file and mobile version but can't get the buttons to work in android devices **(it works in internet explorer but not Google chrome)**. Any ideas of what I have done wrong?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
<script src="C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Ja\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Ja\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
            //get collapse content selector
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

            //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
              if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                                //change the button label to be 'Show'
                toggle_switch.html('Info▼');
              }else{
                                //change the button label to be 'Hide'
                toggle_switch.html('Info▲');
              }
            });
          });

        }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the path to your jQuery script.

```
<script src="C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Ja\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Ja\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

The path to `jquery-1.11.1.js` and `jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js` should be relative to the HTML file you packaged with PhoneGap.